# How to prevent Windows 8 computer from periodically checking a Samba share

Tags: windows, samba, network-attached-storage, qnap

My Windows 8 box keeps nagging my QNAP TS-112 NAS, preventing it from spinning down its disk. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

The connection log on the NAS looks like this:

```
2013-03-07  09:45:19    guest               192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login OK
2013-03-07  09:13:16    guest               192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login OK
2013-03-07  08:57:03    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
2013-03-07  08:56:15    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
2013-03-07  08:55:18    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
2013-03-07  08:54:48    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
2013-03-07  08:51:37    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
2013-03-07  08:46:59    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
2013-03-07  08:46:06    my-ms-acc@gmail.com 192.168.1.103   arthur  SAMBA   --- Login Fail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, just a workaround: disabled NetBIOS to get rid of this.